# Python 3 CSV not writing

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

When I open my csv file I see nothing. Is this the right way to build a csv file? Just trying to learn it all. Thanks for all your help.

```
    import csv
    from urllib.request import urlopen
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    html = urlopen("http://shop.nordstrom.com/c/designer-handbags?dept=8000001&origin=topnav#category=b60133547&type=category&color=&price=&brand=&stores=&instoreavailability=false&lastfilter=&sizeFinderId=0&resultsmode=&segmentId=0&page=1&partial=1&pagesize=100&contextualsortcategoryid=0")
    nordHandbags = BeautifulSoup(html)
    bagList = nordHandbags.findAll("a", {"class":"title"})

    f = csv.writer(open("./nordstrom.csv", "w"))
    f.writerow(["Product Title"])

    for title in bagList:
        productTitles = title.contents[0]
        f.writerow([productTitles])
```

Comment: you would need to give example of `html` you are using. Also, are you not even seeing the `'Product Title'` header?

Comment: I have added the HTML. I am also not seeing Product Title Header no. I am using Windows and Python 3.4.3

Comment: are you checking the correct file? It seems like unless there is an error, you should atleast always get the header.

Comment: It is creating the file when I run the script, could this be a issue?

Answer (score 0):

Really hard to see how you could fail to have at least a `"Product Title"` header in that file. Are you checking the file *after* you have tgerminated the Python interpreter? This, because there is no explicit close of the file in that code, and until it is closed, its contents may be cached in memory.

More Pythonic, and avoiding this problem, is

```
 with open("./nordstrom.csv", "w") as csvfile:
    f = csv.writer( csvfile)
    f.writerow(["Product Title"])
    # etc.

 pass # close the with block, csvfile is now closed.
```

Also (grasping at straws)  are you opening the file with a text editor to check it, or just using the `type` command in Windows cmd.exe?  Because, if the file doesn't contain an explicit LF, the `C:\wherever\ >`prompt may overwrite the header before you see it.